# How can I troubleshoot 'SSL connection could not be established' error with Genesys Cloud API in C#?

Tags: c#, ssl, httpclient, genesys

I'm calling the genesys cloud which shows the error

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
```

The inner exception is showing that

```
System.IO.IOException
Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.
```

I'm using Httpclient in my project and I couldn't find the issue from the search.

I tried searching the google and couldn't find an soulution

Comment: Does this help? [Enable network tracing in dotnet core](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/64977)